# setting the correct table structure to prevent duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key, unique

im doing a quite simple database in which i need to connect people as friends.

In my first column i have user_id and in the second one i have friend_id. What i want to achieve is to prevent a duplicate entry.

for example i want to have something like this:

user_id ; friend_id

1 ; 2

1 ; 3

1 ; 4

and so on

and prevent this:

1 ; 2

1 ; 3

**1 ; 3**

1 ; 4

**1 ; 4**

iv tried everything. If i set user_id as primary or unique, it wont allow me 2 entries with user_id = 1;

any help? thanks

Comment: Create a composite primary key (`user_id, friend_id`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110349/how-can-define-a-composite-primary-key-in-sql) answer states, a composite primary key such as `(user_id, friend_id)` won't allow you to use the index if you query only `friend_id`. You can alternatively create a `UNIQUE` key on `(user_id, friend_id)`.