# Is there such a thing as a compund primary key in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I am busy designing a log table which certain entries will be stored in, I have simplified the problem for this question.

Here is an example of a standard table:

```
bigInt: PK | int:client_id | datetime: time | string:data
```

Now the way I see it, the PK in this case is not really needed in terms of me querying the data which I need? Is there a way you could create a virtual / compound primary key?

So in the case above, you could identity this row, buy a compound PK of `client_id` and `time`.
This way you would save on having to store a useless integer for every entry?

Or an I missing something important about the primary key?

Comment: easy search gives many results: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1110364/1692632

Comment: The primary key in SQL Server is by default also the **clustering key**, which is duplicated into all nonclustered indices on that table. Therefore, the clsutering key should be unique and narrow - using multiple columns as your PK usually tends to be less ideal. I've seen many cases where **adding** an *useless integer* actually makes the whole table **SMALLER** in the end (table data including the index sizes) as compared to using a bloated, compound primary key

Comment: So you saying the 8bytes the pk uses wont hard the table that much, as there are other benefits to having it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible to use a compound primary key in SQL server.

`PK`, on the other hand, is what's called a **surrogate key**: A key field which is not strictly necessary, but which provides easy access to a row.

More importantly, a surrogate key *never changes*: `client_id` and `time` (the **natural key**), have some business meaning, and, thus, might need to be modified, which can be a hassle when other tables reference them as a foreign key.

The Wikipedia article on [Surrogate Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) provides a lot of information on the pros and cons of both approaches.