# Adding a CONSTRAINT to a Partial Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql

I am relatively new to using SQL, and MySQL in specific.

I have the following table definition, and need to add a general constraint to it which I will explain shortly.

```
    CREATE TABLE `ProjInvestigat` (
    `projectID` INT,
    `principalInvestigator` NUMERIC(8,0) ZEROFILL,
    `coInvestigator` NUMERIC(8,0) ZEROFILL,
    PRIMARY KEY (projectID, principalInvestigator, coInvestigator)
);
```

I can have multiple instances of a projectID and principalInvesigator in the table, as long as the coInvesigator is different.  i.e.

```
     projID principID   coInvestID  
     15     17          27      OKAY
     15     17          37      OKAY
     15     27          47      NOT OKAY, I need to prevent having two principal investigators on the same project.
```

I know to add a CONSTRAINT on the table definition, or in an ALTER TABLE statement, but what do I state to enforce this policy?  How do I approach this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To clarify, here are the constraints of this project.

Comment: Each project is managed by one professor, aka the projects principal investigator, AND Professors can manage or work on multiple projects

Comment: You don't need to do anything. A `PRIMARY KEY` is also a `UNIQUE` constraint. FYI, the only kinds of constraints that MySQL supports are `UNIQUE KEY` and `FOREIGN KEY`. It will allow you to write other constraints, but ignores them.

Comment: I think you would need to use triggers in MySQL for this.

Comment: @Barmar . . . And `NULL` constraints ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't even think of that as a constraint, I consider it part of the datatype.

Comment: @Barmar . . . In fact, I do rather agree with you, but it turns out to technically be a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Before filling your base, you have to write a script which allows you to verify if a project has two main investigators or not.
You can also look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110349/how-can-i-define-a-composite-primary-key-in-sql) , maybe it's helpful.

Comment: I should have also mentioned the definitions of the two base relations,  here they are.  BTW foreign key constraints were added after in an alter table statement.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `Professors` (
          `SNN` NUMERIC(8,0) ZEROFILL NOT NULL CHECK (VALUE        BETWEEN 0 AND 99999999),
          `fName` VARCHAR(20),
          `lName` VARCHAR(20),
          `age` SMALLINT CHECK (VALUE BETWEEN 0 AND 99),
          `rank` VARCHAR(15),
          `researchSpeciality` VARCHAR(30),
          PRIMARY KEY (SNN)
         );

Comment: CREATE TABLE `Projects` (
 `projectNumber` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `sponsorName` VARCHAR(20),
 `projectName` VARCHAR(30),
 `startingDate` DATE CHECK (VALUE > 2005-JAN-01),
 `endingDate` DATE CHECK (VALUE > 2005-JAN-01 AND VALUE > startingDate),
 `budget` DECIMAL(10,2),
 PRIMARY KEY (projectNumber)
);

Comment: @mike If you have more details, put them in the question, not comments.