# microsoft access many to many relationship and two primary keys in junction table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I confused about these two concept? are they same or different?
I know what is manay to many relationship and we have one junction table which connect two other tables with two FK it means in junction table I have three feilds one ID primarykey and two FK but what is defferences between that and when we have junction table which has Two PK and then relate other tables.

first case  junction table contains     ID PK  ,   user id Fk  ,   Country id FK

second case junction table  contains        user id Pk ,Country id PK

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Many to Many Relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238237/many-to-many-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

Concepts are different. In first case you can have more than one relation between the same rows in main tables, in second - not, unique index won't allow this.