# Assignment Table INSERT INTO prevent duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to create a statement for my PHP function where I have an `UserID` and an `InteressenID` and update my `userinteressen` table depending on what the user has checked. I don't want duplicates in that table.

I have found the [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) in documentation, however, that doesn't work since in the table doesn't have an `UNIQUE` row set.
Due working with MySQL, I don't have the `MERGE` statement.
Since I receive the `InteressenID` from my PHP function, there's no need for a `JOIN`. I tried `INSERT IGNORE` described [here](http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html), but it returned Error #1064
For deleting, I was thinking about first setting the `InteressenID` to 0 and delete them afterwards.

The tables:

**User**

```
ID | Name
---+--------
1  | "Agathe"
2  | "Bernd"
3  | "Charlie"
```

**Interessen**

```
ID | Name
---+------------
1  | "Cars"
2  | "Sport"
3  | "Languages"
```

**userinteressen**

```
User | Interessen
-----+-----------
1    | 2
1    | 3
2    | 2
```

My not working attempts:

```
INSERT INTO userinteressen VALUES('$id','$interesse')
SELECT *
WHERE userinteressen.User IS NULL AND userinteressen.Interesse IS NULL;

INSERT IGNORE INTO `userinteressen`
SET `User`= 1
`Interesse`= 2;
```

More Informations:
I'm using PDO.
The userinteressen-table was created by using the interface of phpmyadmin, thus I had no real idea, what the DB looked like.

I exported the database to get some insights. I'm new to databases and had mostly theory. Here are the statements created by the Engine:

```
--
-- Indices for Tabelle `userinteressen`
--
ALTER TABLE `userinteressen`
  ADD KEY `User` (`User`,`Interesse`),
  ADD KEY `Interesse` (`Interesse`);

--
-- Constraints of table `userinteressen`
--
ALTER TABLE `userinteressen`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `userinteressen_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`User`) REFERENCES `user` (`UserID`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `userinteressen_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Interesse`) REFERENCES `interessen` (`InteressenID`);

COMMIT;
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused. Given that we don't want duplicates in that table, why wouldn't we enforce a unique constraint, by created a unique index on the combination of the two columns?  With a unique constraint, we can use `INSERT IGNORE` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` e.g. `ALTER TABLE userinteressen ADD UNIQUE KEY userinteressen_UX1 (user, interessen)`.  (Alternatively, we could define the PRIMARY KEY to be a composite key, those same two columns.  Likely we are also going to need an index with `interessen` as the leading column.  (InnoDB will automatically create indexes to support foreign keys.)

Comment: The reason why I didn't enforce a unique constraint is I wasn't aware of this possibility. I'm new to databases (only had it for one year and we started with MS Access). That's a helpful information, thank you!

Comment: More informations about "[How to update a junction table?](https://giustino.blog/how-to-update-a-junction-table/)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mysql REPLACE:**

Is `User` and `Interesse` in your [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) `userinteressen` a [composite PRIMARY KEY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110349/how-can-i-define-a-composite-primary-key-in-sql)? Then you can use mysql [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) instead of INSERT:

```
REPLACE INTO `userinteressen`
SET `User`= 1
`Interesse`= 2;
```

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted. See
>   Section 13.2.6, “INSERT Syntax”.

But there is no solution for unchecked "interesse". So you need something to delete relations in `userinteressen`, when a user unchecks one or more.

Example to delete:

```
DELETE FROM `userinteressen` WHERE `Interesse` NOT IN (1,2,3) AND `User` = 1;
```

Replace (1,2,3) with the selected interesse id´s

**Delete all relations before inserting:**

You can also delete all relations (tuples) and insert the current selected again. This also allows for user to uncheck a "interesse" and its deleted:

```
// ...
DELETE FROM `userinteressen` WHERE `User` = 1
// ...
foreach($selectedInteressen as $id) {
    // ...
    INSERT INTO `userinteressen`
    SET `User`= 1
    `Interesse`= $id;
    // ...
}
```

*NOTICE: I dont know which interface you are using (PDO, mysqli, ...?) so i simplified the example*

Comment: I'm using PDO as interface. I'm not sure what you mean with combined PRIMARY KEY though.
`ALTER TABLE `userinteressen`
  ADD KEY `User` (`User`,`Interesse`),
  ADD KEY `Interesse` (`Interesse`);

I'm updating my post for more information.

Comment: Oh its called composite PRIMARY KEY and not combined PRIMARY KEY. I updated my answer. Its a PRIMARY KEY over more then one field. `PRIMARY KEY (User, Interesse)`. [How can I define a composite primary key in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110349/how-can-i-define-a-composite-primary-key-in-sql)