# Set multiple "primary keys" on one AccountID

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, database-administration

This seems like a simple problem. However, I'm blocked.

I have 6 Product ID's: `1001`, `1002`, `1003`, `1004`, `1005`, `1006`.

In a table, I also have a list of account IDs. Each Account ID can have one of many product IDs(1-6), but no duplicates.

How do I add a constraint to allow multiple AccountID's in a table that could up to 1-6 product ID's but none of the productID's per one account could be duplicated?

Example Table :

Good Table

```
Account_ID  ProductID
138777  100004
138777  100003
--------------
21252   100003
138778  100003
138779  100004
138780  100003
138781  100001
138782  100004
```

Bad table

```
Account_ID  ProductID
138777  100003
138777  100003
---------------
21252   100003
138778  100003
138779  100004
138780  100003
138781  100001
138782  100004
```

What's the most logical way of implementing this constraint?

Comment: It appears that a [unique constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15) will meet your needs. Indexing may improve query performance and can be done both ways, i.e. both `Account_Id, Product_Id` and `Product_Id, Account_Id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the `composite primary key` on the column `Account_ID` and `ProductID`.

You can learn from this SO post [How can I define a composite primary key in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110349/how-can-i-define-a-composite-primary-key-in-sql)

You can alter the table if already created to add the composite primary key as shown below.

```
ALTER TABLE < YourTableName > ADD CONSTRAINT [name of PK, e.g. PK_AccountProduct] PRIMARY KEY (
    Account_ID
    ,ProductID
    )
```

You can do it in the SQL Server management studio by opening the table in the design view and selecting both the columns and right-click and set the composite/primary key.

In SSMS it looks like as shown below:

[image]