# How i prevent duplicate row by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have 3 column

```
stu_id

sub_code

lecture_date
```

What I want is that the id and code columns cannot be repeated. I am trying but it only allows me to select a primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE example(
   stu_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   sub_code VARCHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
   lecture_date DATE
```

Comment: i have put the solution to your problem now the id and the code adapt it depending on your data types

Comment: By definition, a table can only have one primary key, but you can use the `UNIQUE KEY` constraint over the columns you want to be unique.

Comment: actually my friend if the primary key is not put next to the data but at the bottom as primary key(column1,column2) it catches it perfectly I do it this way in fact. If not, check it out on the next page @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier :  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/148

Comment: the fact that two fields are primary keys is known as a composite primary key. For more information see this page that explains it @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier : https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-composite-key#:~:text=A%20composite%20key%20in%20MySQL,only%20when%20they%20are%20combined.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1110364/12464880

Comment: @Khaled Do you want the unicity to be over two columns, eg there can't be any repeating sub_code for the same stu_id, or by column, eg there can be only one sub_code in the whole table? In the comments on the answer you say you want to prevent duplicates in *the same day*? but you've put the indexes over id and code? which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want both fields to be **unique**, you can make the first one as `primary key` and the second one `unique`.

The `UNIQUE` constraint ensures that all values in a column are different.

Example :

```
CREATE TABLE examp (
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   cod VARCHAR(3) UNIQUE,
   fecha DATE
);
```

**Then you do the insert**

```
INSERT into youTable values(youfirtcolumn,yousecondcolumn,youthirdcolumn);
```

**Example :**

```
INSERT INTO youTable VALUES(1,'A1',NOW()),
                          (2,'A2','2022-04-03');
```

**GOOD EXAMPLE :**  [<kbd>THIS WORKS</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/195)

**FAIL EXAMPLE :**  [<kbd>THIS WORKS</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/196)

Comment: bro but that is not my problem , i mean main concept of prevent duplicate values in same day in any case

Comment: no i mean , when i insert 1, 'A1',curdate
if i try to insert same values again restrict that
and when i insert 1,'A2',curdate its ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243540/discussion-between-khaled-salah-and-javier-g-raya).

Comment: thx bro , i talked about didnt allow to add 2 p k in same table bcz i try from structure not by query